# Copying variables of one inner struct to other inner struct using a function that takes address of one inner struct as a parameter

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have a complex structure which looks like this.

```
struct a
{
  struct b
  {
    int b_inner_int;
    char b_inner_char;
  }x;

  struct c
  {
    int c_inner_int;
    char c_inner_char;
  }y;

}z;
```

I use a function, that takes address of "struct c" as an argument. Now I want this function to copy the values of "struct c" to "struct b". The function call that I make in the main function may look like this.

```
copy_val(&z.y);
```

Now, how do I define copy_val? Any suggestions?
If i define a pointer of type struct c, like below it isn't working.

```
void copy_val(struct c *addr)
{
    struct c *tmp=addr;
    int tmp_int=tmp->c_inner_int;
    int tmp_char=tmp->c_inner_char;

    tmp=tmp-1; /** assuming that b and c are of same type and decrementing pointer by 1 takes to beginning of b **/

    tmp->b_inner_int=tmp_int;
    tmp->b_inner_char=tmp_char;
}
```

Comment: Try something, share it, and show what you have tried, and then if you had problems, we can discuss it.  SO isn't the place to have us write your code.  I will say that a function that is copying from one to the other will need both inner structure addresses passed to it, if you insist on passing the inner structures..

Comment: Don't you mean that you want to copy from the `c` structure to the `b` structure?

Comment: yes that was a typo... I mean copying from c to b... @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @JohnH Was editing the post... I have posted what I have tried now

Comment: And why not simply have a `copy_val` function that takes the whole `a` structure, and then do e.g. `z.x = z.y;`

Comment: if struct b and struct c are the same then just define a single struct and use it for two different variables.  Then it would be a matter of just assigning one variable to the other.

Comment: and I would not count on the decrement of the tmp pointer to get you to struct b either.  no telling what the compiler may have done to the struct a layout.

Comment: Yes, use `offsetof` (or just pass the address of `struct a` in the first place) to get the address of `struct b` (I think, that's still not strictly conforming, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct a
{
  struct b
  {
    int b_inner_int;
    char b_inner_char;
  }x;

  struct c
  {
    int c_inner_int;
    char c_inner_char;
  }y;

}z;

void copy_val(struct c *addr){
    size_t offset_c = offsetof(struct a, y);
    size_t offset_b = offsetof(struct a, x);
    struct b *bp = (struct b*)((char*)addr - offset_c + offset_b);
    bp->b_inner_int = addr->c_inner_int;
    bp->b_inner_char = addr->c_inner_char;
}

int main(void){
    z.y.c_inner_int = 1;
    z.y.c_inner_char = '1';
    copy_val(&z.y);
    printf("%d, %c\n", z.x.b_inner_int, z.x.b_inner_char);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dang; I had the same idea, but got stuck with aliasing hazards.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you want to take the address of a structure *member*, and reference other members based on that.

That's a bit iffy; the natural thing to do would be to take the address of the top-level *structure* whose members you want to work with, i.e. a `struct a`.

Also, it can be simplified:

```
struct a
{
  struct b
  {
    int b_inner_int;
    char b_inner_char;
  } x, y;
} z;
```

With that done, you can do just:

```
z.x = z.y;
```

to copy the entire value of type `struct b`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass like this `copy_val(&z.y);` you can't catch it in proper way because you have structure inside structure. so try to pass whole structure and copy it-

```
copy_val(&z);
```

Try the following code-

```
void copy_val(struct z *addr)
{
addr->x.b_inner_int= addr->y.c_inner_int;
addr->x.b_inner_char= addr->y.c_inner_char;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that `b` and `c` are the same type is invalid, according to the C standard section 6.2.7 p.1 (emphasis mine):

> ...if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared
>   with **the same name**.

Because the structs use different member names, they are *not* considered compatible, thus your assumption is invalid.

Further, even if they are the *exact* same type, the `tmp=tmp-1;` statement is not valid: while `sizeof(struct b)` *may* report something like 8, this does not mean there's zero padding between the two structures.

Instead, you should use the `offsetof` macro to get the address of `z`, given the address of `z.y`:

```
struct a *z = (struct a *)((char *)addr - offsetof(struct a, y));
```

Note, however, that this may break aliasing assumptions, as part of the object pointing to `z` is also pointed to by `y`, but the pointers are not compatible.

Comment: This doesn't break aliasing assumptions, what `z` points to, _is_ a `struct a` object (so in `*z` declared and effective types match). But I think, it's out-of-bounds access: `(char *)addr` is a pointer to a `sizeof *addr `-sized array, pointing to its first byte. An implementation with bounds-checking (which is allowed) may throw an exception.

Comment: @mafso actually, since `addr` is assumed to be the address of a `struct c` inside a `struct a`, `addr` is a pointer to the *middle* of a `sizeof(struct c)`-sized array, it's not OOB. Consider `char y[100] = ...; char *z = &y[20];`, then `z[-15]` is not OOB (because it refers to `y[5]`).

Comment: Your example is different IMO (and defined, just as you said). My concerns are a little harder to describe and I think your answer is OK as-is (besides there are certainly no aliasing-problems here). Are you interested in a discussion on that, maybe in chat?

Comment: @mafso sure, but I'm busy for the next few hours

Comment: @mafso alright, I've got a chat over at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59294/pointers-aliasing-and-undefined-behavior

Answer (score -1):

```
include <stdio.h>

struct a
{
  struct b
  {
    int b_inner_int;
    char b_inner_char;
  }x;

  struct c
  {
    int c_inner_int;
    char c_inner_char;
  }y;

}z;

void copy_val(struct c *c_pointer)
{
    struct b *tmp = (struct b *) (c_pointer-1);

    tmp->b_inner_int = c_pointer->c_inner_int;
    tmp->b_inner_char = c_pointer->c_inner_char;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    struct a test;

    test.y.c_inner_int = 32; 
    test.y.c_inner_char = 'A';

    copy_val(&test.y);

    printf("b inner int : %d\n", test.x.b_inner_int);
    printf("b inner char %c\n", test.x.b_inner_char);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is effectively what OP described as trying, and it didn't work. The use of `c_pointer - 1` is not valid.

Comment: OP code didn't work because his tmp pointer was of type struct c *. I do agree that using offsetof is a much better answer, but I tested my code on my machine, it does work. I wouldn't use it, though.

Comment: Just because it works on your computer doesn't mean it's not necessarily correct. After all, undefined behavior includes working as intended.