# Can a "container_of" macro ever be strictly-conforming?

Tags: c, pointers, standards

A commonly-used macro in the linux kernel (and other places) is `container_of`, which is (basically) defined as  follows:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) (((type) *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof((type), (member))))
```

Which basically allows recovery of a "parent" structure given a pointer to one of its members:

```
struct foo {
    char ch;
    int bar;
};
...
struct foo f = ...
int *ptr = &f.bar; // 'ptr' points to the 'bar' member of 'struct foo' inside 'f'
struct foo *g = container_of(ptr, struct foo, bar);
// now, 'g' should point to 'f', i.e. 'g == &f'
```

However, it's not entirely clear whether the subtraction contained within `container_of` is considered undefined behavior.

On one hand, because `bar` inside `struct foo` is only a single integer, then only `*ptr` should be valid (as well as `ptr + 1`). Thus, the `container_of` effectively produces an expression like `ptr - sizeof(int)`, which is undefined behavior (even without dereferencing).

On the other hand, §6.3.2.3 p.7 of the C standard states that converting a pointer to a different type and back again shall produce the same pointer. Therefore, "moving" a pointer to the middle of a `struct foo` object, then back to the beginning *should* produce the original pointer.

The main concern is the fact that implementations are allowed to check for out-of-bounds indexing at runtime. My interpretation of this and the aforementioned pointer equivalence requirement is that the bounds must be preserved across pointer casts (this includes pointer decay - otherwise, how could you use a pointer to iterate across an array?). Ergo, while `ptr` may only be an `int` pointer, and neither `ptr - 1` nor `*(ptr + 1)` are valid, `ptr` should still have some notion of being in the middle of a structure, so that `(char *)ptr - offsetof(struct foo, bar)` *is* valid (even if the pointer is equal to `ptr - 1` in practice).

Finally, I came across the fact that if you have something like:

```
int arr[5][5] = ...
int *p = &arr[0][0] + 5;
int *q = &arr[1][0];
```

while it's undefined behavior to dereference `p`, the pointer by itself is valid, and required to compare equal to `q` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832970/does-c99-guarantee-that-arrays-are-contiguous)). This means that `p` and `q` *compare* the same, but can be different in some implementation-defined manner (such that only `q` can be dereferenced). This could mean that given the following:

```
// assume same 'struct foo' and 'f' declarations
char *p = (char *)&f.bar;
char *q = (char *)&f + offsetof(struct foo, bar);
```

`p` and `q` compare the same, but could have different boundaries associated with them, as the casts to `(char *)` come from pointers to incompatible types.

---

To sum it all up, the C standard isn't entirely clear about this type of behavior, and attempting to apply other parts of the standard (or, at least my interpretations of them) leads to conflicts. So, is it possible to define `container_of` in a strictly-conforming manner? If so, is the above definition correct?

---

*This was discussed [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59294/pointers-aliasing-and-undefined-behavior) after comments on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25288333/2478565) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287966/copying-variables-of-one-inner-struct-to-other-inner-struct-using-a-function-tha) question.*

Comment: It seems like it should be OK: Since the original pointer points into the middle of a large object, it's OK to convert it to a char pointer and treat it as pointing to an element of the object representation of the large object and perform arithmetic on it.

Comment: The C spec is completely ambiguous as to the meaning of the term 'the array object' when you have arrays of arrays (or structs containing arrays, since the struct objects are implicitly arrays of size 1) -- it could mean either the inner array or the containing array.  Combine this with the fact that the spec requires an implementation to allow treating any object as a sequence of bytes (chars) that can be copied around, and you have a situation where it seems like all this sort of pointer manipulation has to be allowed, but the spec does not clearly say it.

Comment: "[…] converting a pointer to a different type and back again shall produce the same pointer"—to be precise, a pointer which "shall compare equal to the original pointer". As I read it, this does not necessarily imply the "same" regarding bounds information.

Comment: The standard also isn't clear about accessing an object through a converted pointer - it only mentions the alignment requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TLDR

It is a matter of debate among language lawyers as to whether programs using `container_of` are *strictly conforming*, but pragmatists using the `container_of` idiom are in good company and are unlikely to run into issues running programs compiled with mainstream tool chains on mainstream hardware. In other words:

- *strictly conforming*: debated
- *conforming*: yes, for all practical purposes, in most situations

## What can be said today

1. There is no language in the standard C17 standard that unambiguously requires support for the `container_of` idiom.
2. There are [defect reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26477671/2442218) that suggest the standard intends to allow implementations room to forbid the `container_of` idiom by tracking "provenance" (i.e. the valid bounds) of objects along with pointers. However, these alone are not normative.
3. There is recent activity in the [C memory object model study group](https://github.com/C-memory-object-model-study-group) that aims to provide more rigor to this and similar questions.  See [Clarifying the C memory object model - N2012](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2012.htm) from 2016, [Pointers are more abstract than you might expect](https://stefansf.de/post/pointers-are-more-abstract-than-you-might-expect/) from 2018, and [A Provenance-aware Memory Object Model for C - N2676](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2676.pdf) from 2021.

Depending on when you read this, there may be newer documents available at the [WG14 document log](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/wg14_document_log).  Additionally, Peter Sewell collects related reference material here: [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cerberus/](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cerberus/).  These documents do not change what a *strictly conforming* program is today (in 2021, for versions C17 and older), but they suggest that the answer may change in newer versions of the standard.

## Background

### What is the `container_of` idiom?

This code demonstrates the idiom by expanding the contents of the macro usually seen implementing the idiom:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct foo {
    long first;
    short second;
};

void container_of_idiom(void) {
    struct foo f;

    char* b = (char*)&f.second;        /* Line A */
    b -= offsetof(struct foo, second); /* Line B */
    struct foo* c = (struct foo*)b;    /* Line C */
}
```

In the above case, a `container_of` macro would typically take a `short*` argument intended to point to the `second` field of a `struct foo`.  It would also take arguments for `struct foo` and `second`, and would expand to an expression returning `struct foo*`.  It would employ the logic seen in lines A-C above.

The question is: is this code strictly conforming?

First, let's define "strictly conforming"

> C17 4 (5-7) Conformance
>
> 5. A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard. It shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit.
> 6. [...] A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program. [...] A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.
> 7. A conforming program is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation.

(For brevity I omitted the definition of "freestanding" implementations, as it concerns limitations on the standard library not relevant here.)

From this we see that strict conformance is quite strict, but a conforming implementation is allowed to define additional behavior as long as it does not alter the behavior of a strictly conforming program.  In practice, almost all implementations do this; this is the "practical" definition that most C programs are written against.

For the purposes of this answer I'll contain my answer to *strictly conforming* programs, and talk about merely *conforming* programs at the end.

### Defect reports

The language standard itself is somewhat unclear on the question, but several defect reports shed more light on the issue.

### DR 51

[DR 51](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_051.html) ask questions of this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
    char x[1];
};

int main() {
    struct A *p = (struct A *)malloc(sizeof(struct A) + 100);
    p->x[5] = '?'; /* This is the key line */
    return p->x[5];
}
```

The response to the DR includes (emphasis mine):

> Subclause 6.3.2.1 describes limitations on pointer arithmetic, in connection with array subscripting. (See also subclause 6.3.6.) Basically, it **permits an implementation to tailor how it represents pointers to the size of the objects they point at**. Thus, the expression `p->x[5]` may fail to designate the expected byte, even though the malloc call ensures that the byte is present. The idiom, while common, is **not strictly conforming**.

Here we have the first indication that the standard allows implementations to "tailor" pointer representations based on the objects pointed at, and that pointer arithmetic that "leaves" the valid range of the *original* object pointed to is not strictly conforming.

[DR 72](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_072.html) ask questions of this program:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double T;
struct hacked {
    int size;
    T data[1];
};

struct hacked *f(void)
{
    T *pt;
    struct hacked *a;
    char *pc;

    a = malloc(sizeof(struct hacked) + 20 * sizeof(T));
    if (a == NULL) return NULL;
    a->size = 20;

    /* Method 1 */
    a->data[8] = 42; /* Line A /*

   /* Method 2 */
    pt = a->data;
    pt += 8; /* Line B /*
    *pt = 42;

    /* Method 3 */
    pc = (char *)a;
    pc += offsetof(struct hacked, data);
    pt = (T *)pc; /* Line C */
    pt += 8;      /* Line D */
    *pt = 6 * 9;
    return a;
}
```

Astute readers will notice that `/* Method 3 */` above is much like the `container_of` idiom.  I.e. it takes a pointer to a struct type, converts it to `char*`, does some pointer arithmetic that takes the `char*` outside the range of the original struct, and uses the pointer.

The committee responded by saying `/* Line C */` was strictly conforming but `/* Line D */` was not strictly conforming by the same argument given for DR 51 above.  Further, the committee said that the answers "are not affected if `T` has `char` type."

## Verdict: `container_of` is not strictly conforming (probably)

The `container_of` idiom takes a pointer to a struct's subobject, converts the pointer to `char*`, and performs pointer arithmetic that moves the pointer outside the subobject.  This is the same set of operations discussed in DR 51 and 72 apply.  There is clear intent on the part of the committee.  They hold that the standard "**permits an implementation to tailor how it represents pointers to the size of the objects they point at**" and thus "**the idiom, while common, is not strictly conforming.**"

One might argue that `container_of` side steps the issue by doing the pointer arithmetic in the domain of `char*` pointers, but the committee says the answer is "**not affected if `T` has `char` type.**"

## May the `container_of` idiom be used in practice?

No, if you want to be strict and use only code that is not clearly *strictly conforming* according to current language standards.

Yes, if you are a pragmatist and believe that an idiom widely used in Linux, FreeBSD, Microsoft Windows C code is enough to label the idiom *conforming* in practice.

As noted above, implementations are allowed to guarantee behavior in ways not required by the standard.  On a practical note, the `container_of` idiom is used in the Linux kernel and many other projects.  It is easy for implementations to support on modern hardware.  Various "sanitizer" systems such as Address Sanitizer, Undefined Behavior Sanitizer, Purify, Valgrind, etc., all allow this behavior.  On systems with flat address spaces, and even segmented ones, various "pointer games" are common (e.g. converting to integral values and masking off low order bits to find page boundaries, etc).  These techniques are so common in C code today that it is very unlikely that such idioms will cease to function on any commonly supported system now or in the future.

In fact, I found one implementation of a bounds checker that gives a different interpretation of C semantics in its paper. The quotes are from the following paper: Richard W. M. Jones and Paul H. J. Kelly. Backwards-compatible bounds checking for arrays and pointers in C programs. In Third International Workshop on Automated Debugging (editors M. Kamkarand D. Byers), volume 2 (1997), No. 009 of Linköping Electronic Articles in Computer and Information Science. Linköping University Electronic Press, Linköping, Sweden.  ISSN 1401-9841, May 1997 pp. 13–26.  URL http://www.ep.liu.se/ea/cis/1997/009/02/

> ANSI C conveniently allows us to define an *object* as the fundamental unit of memory allocation. [...] Operations are permitted which manipulate pointers within objects, but pointer operations are not permitted to cross between two objects.  There is no ordering defined between objects, and the programmer should never be allowed to make assumptions about how objects are arranged in memory.

> Bounds checking is not blocked or weakened by the use of a cast (i.e. type coercion).  Cast can properly be used to change the type of the object to which a pointer refers, but cannot be used to turn a pointer to one object into a pointer to another.  A corollary is that bounds checking is not type checking: it does not prevent storage from being declared with one data structure and used with another.  More subtly, note that for this reason, bounds checking in C cannot easily validate use of arrays of `structs` which contain arrays in turn.

> Every valid pointer-valued expression in C derives its result from exactly one original storage object.  If the result of the pointer calculation refers to a different object, it is invalid.
> This language is quite definitive but take note the paper was published in 1997, *before* the DR reports above were written and responded to. The best way to interpret the bounds checking system described in the paper is as a *conforming* implementation of C, but not one that detects all non-*strictly conforming* programs.  I do see similarities between this paper and [A Provenance-aware Memory Object Model for C - N2676](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2676.pdf) from 2021, however, so in the future the ideas similar to the ones quoted above *might* be codified in the language standard.

The [C memory object model study group](https://github.com/C-memory-object-model-study-group) is a treasure trove of discussions related to `container_of` and many other closely related problems.  From their mailing list archive we have these mentions of the `container_of` idiom:

[2.5.4 Q34 Can one move among the members of a struct using representation-pointer arithmetic and casts?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2222.htm#q34-can-one-move-among-the-members-of-a-struct-using-representation-pointer-arithmetic-and-casts)

> The standard is ambiguous on the interaction between the allowable pointer arithmetic (on unsigned char* representation pointers) and subobjects. For example, consider:
>
> Example `cast_struct_inter_member_1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct { float f; int i; } st;
int main() {
  st s = {.f=1.0, .i=1};
  int *pi = &(s.i);
  unsigned char *pci = ((unsigned char *)pi);
  unsigned char *pcf = (pci - offsetof(st,i))
    + offsetof(st,f);
  float *pf = (float *)pcf;
  *pf = 2.0;  // is this free of undefined behaviour?
  printf("s.f=%f *pf=%f  s.i=%i\n",s.f,*pf,s.i);
}
```

> This forms an unsigned char* pointer to the second member (i) of a struct, does arithmetic on that using offsetof to form an unsigned char* pointer to the first member, casts that into a pointer to the type of the first member (f), and uses that to write.
>
> In practice we believe that this is all supported by most compilers and it is used in practice, e.g. as in the Container idiom of Chisnall et al. [ASPLOS 2015], where they discuss container macros that take a pointer to a structure member and compute a pointer to the structure as a whole. They see it heavily used by one of the example programs they studied. We are told that Intel's MPX compiler does not support the container macro idiom, while Linux, FreeBSD, and Windows all rely on it.
>
> The standard says (6.3.2.3p7): "...When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.". This licenses the construction of the unsigned char* pointer pci to the start of the representation of s.i (presuming that a structure member is itself an "object", which itself is ambiguous in the standard), but allows it to be used only to access the representation of s.i.
>
> The offsetof definition in stddef.h, 7.19p3, " offsetof(type,member-designator) which expands to an integer constant expression that has type size_t, the value of which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by member-designator, from the beginning of its structure (designated by type", implies that the calculation of pcf gets the correct numerical address, but does not say that it can be used, e.g. to access the representation of s.f. As we saw in the discussion of provenance, in a post-DR260 world, the mere fact that a pointer has the correct address does not necessarily mean that it can be used to access that memory without giving rise to undefined behaviour.
>
> Finally, if one deems pcf to be a legitimate char* pointer to the representation of s.f, then the standard says that it can be converted to a pointer to any object type if sufficiently aligned, which for float* it will be. 6.3.2.3p7: "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned (68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer....". But whether that pointer has the right value and is usable to access memory is left unclear.
>
> This example should be allowed in our de facto semantics but is not clearly allowed in the ISO text.
>
> What needs to be changed in the ISO text to clarify this?
>
> More generally, the ISO text's use of "object" is unclear: does it refer to an allocation, or are struct members, union members, and array elements also "objects"?

Key phrase being "*This example should be allowed in our de facto semantics but is not clearly allowed in the ISO text.*" i.e. I take this to mean the the group documenets like [N2676](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2676.pdf) wish to see `container_of` supported.

However, in a [later message](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-c-memory-object-model/2018-September/msg00006.html#provenance-and-subobjects-container-of-casts):

> 2.2 Provenance and subobjects: container-of casts
>
> A key question is whether one can cast from a pointer to the first member of a struct to the struct as a whole, and then use that to access other members. We discussed it previously in N2222 Q34 Can one move among the members of a struct using representation-pointer arithmetic and casts?, N2222 Q37 Are usable pointers to a struct and to its first member interconvertable?, N2013, and N2012. Some of us had thought that that was uncontroversially allowed in ISO C, by 6.7.2.1p15 ...A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member..., and vice versa..., but others disagree. In practice, this seems to be common in real code, in the "container-of" idiom.
>
> Though someone suggested that the IBM XL C/C++ compiler does not support it. Clarification from WG14 and compiler teams would be very helpful on this point.

With this, the group sums it up nicely: the idiom is widely used, but there is disagreement about what the standard says about it.

Comment: A great post. It provides so much useful material about abstraction that pointer really are.  As I understand the ambiguity comes from insufficient definition of "object".  I think that the strict-conformance of `container_of`-like macros may depend on how the pointer are formed.Do you think that in example 2.5.4 if `int *pi = &(s.i);` was replaced with `int *pi = (int*)((char*)&s + offsetof(st, i));` then the  behavior would be defined?

Comment: Yes I think the distinction you draw holds. The standard says that if you take `(char*)&x` then you can increment/decrement that `char*` across the bytes of the `x` object at will.  The n2676 paper I linked, I think, gives both cases valid semantics. It says that both would point into the same "storage instance" and says pointer arithmetic within any one "storage instance" is valid. The paper says storage instances can't overlap, which implies that containing objects and sub-objects are in the same storage instance. I think this attempts to codify what most would expect intuitively.

Comment: @nmr, yes I misspelled "provenance" there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think its strictly conforming or there's a big defect in the standard. Referring to your last example, the section on pointer arithmetic doesn't give the compiler any leeway to treat `p` and `q` differently. It isn't conditional on how the pointer value was obtained, only what object it points to.

Any interpretation that `p` and `q` could be treated differently in pointer arithmetic would require an interpretation that `p` and `q` do not point to the same object. Since since there's no implementation dependent behaviour in how you obtained `p` and `q` then that would mean they don't point to the same object on any implementation. That would in turn require that `p == q` be false on all implementations, and so would make all actual implementations non-conforming.

Comment: Yes, *what object it points to* is key. The debate seems to center around that question. The standard merely says "the object" but in the case of `char* p = (char *)&f.bar;` the object could be `f` or its subobject `f.bar`. Some argue that the standard allows, but does not require, implementations to restrict the providence of the `p` pointer to the range of bytes in `f.bar`. If `p` is decremented past the first byte of `f.bar`, some argue `p` has undefined value, so equality comparison is undefined, and if so your proof by contradiction would not hold.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to answer this bit.

```
int arr[5][5] = ...
int *p = &arr[0][0] + 5;
int *q = &arr[1][0];
```

This is not UB. It is certain that p is a pointer to an element of the array, provided only that it is within bounds. In each case it points to the 6th element of a 25 element array, and can safely be dereferenced. It can also be incremented or decremented to access other elements of the array.

See n3797 S8.3.4 for C++. The wording is different for C, but the meaning is the same. In effect arrays have a standard layout and are well-behaved with respect to pointers.

---

Let us suppose for a moment that this is not so. What are the implications? We know that the layout of an array int[5][5] is identical to int[25], there can be no padding, alignment or other extraneous information. We also know that once p and q have been formed and given a value, they must be identical in every respect.

The only possibility is that, if the standard says it is UB and the compiler writer implements the standard, then a sufficiently vigilant compiler might either (a) issue a diagnostic based on analysing the data values or (b) apply an optimisation which was dependent on not straying outside the bounds of sub-arrays.

Somewhat reluctantly I have to admit that (b) is at least a possibility. I am led to the rather strange observation that if you can conceal from the compiler your true intentions this code is guaranteed to produce defined behaviour, but if you do it out in the open it may not.

Comment: Did you read [the question linked in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832970/does-c99-guarantee-that-arrays-are-contiguous)? The memory layout and bounds checking are two things, the former being guaranteed and the latter being the question here.

Comment: Yes, I read it and yes they are. That answer was old, the issue was not properly resolved in comments and I don't feel like adding to them. But your comment leads me to a different train of thought...see edit.

Comment: Your (b) is another good point, while the main concern was reliable run-time bounds checking (not compile-time checking as you suggest in (a)). Reading the standard quote given in the linked post (especially the emphasized part and the footnote) makes me believe the standard's intent is to not allow such out-of-bounds access. And yes, this necessarily implies, that pointers comparing equal may differ in their associated bounds information and thus arithmetic/dereferencing may throw an exception for one of them and succeed for the other. Two examples:

Comment: `int p[1]; int q; if(p+1 == &q) /* look if they happen to be contiguous in stack */ { p[1] = 1; /* Does this initialize q? */ }` assuming the `if` branch is entered. I think it's desirably to allow a bounds-checking implementation to catch this nonsense-construct. A less contrived example: `struct { char str1[16], str2[16]; } foo; fgets(str1, 32, stdin);` (Assume no padding, we could have statically asserted `sizeof foo == 32`.) Should this be allowed to throw an exception? We can discuss further on this in chat, if you like, I'm really interested in this topic.

Comment: And btw, I think the answer given there is almost correct, but I think the example for a valid iteration is wrong: `pc = (char *)(&a[0][0]);` is casted from the address of an `int` object, not from an `int[5][5]` object. But the iteration would be strictly conforming with `pc = (char *)&a;`. (And a note: I meant `fgets(foo.str, 32, stdin);` in my last comment, of course.)

Comment: @mafso: Yes, runtime bounds checking on subscripting only. Pointer-to-element cannot carry that info and cannot be UB on sub-arrays because the layout is known. OK to chat, but it's too late here now.

Comment: @david.pfx there's nothing in the standard that says a pointer to an element of an array can't carry information on the originating array. Otherwise, with something like `int x[5], p = &x[2], q = p[3];`, there'd be no way of knowing that `p[3]` refers to `x[5]`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I think the requirement that you can round-trip a pointer through another pointer type, a `void*` or even an integer rules that out. Pointers cannot carry hidden range-checking or subscripting information, nor does anyone expect them to. Arrays might, but only when accessed through an array type.

Comment: @david.pfx: There is no access through an array type, arrays decay to pointers. Arrays always have size information (see `sizeof`), only pointers needed that information for a bounds-checking implementation. Round-trip conversion isn't a problem. A pointer on this platform always carries the valid offsets (say, in bytes) and where it currently points to and on each addition/subtraction/dereferencing, this information is checked. I can't find anything in the standard not allowing this. (I think, the answer to the question here is no, there is no strictly conforming `container_of`.)

Comment: @mafso: Decay is an 'as if' requirement. A compiler generating code for array subscripting can generate different code than pointer arithmetic. No, sizeof only exists at compile time. A pointer with an integral offset would be larger than any integer type. That would break a lot of assumptions, even if the standard allowed it. Until someone can describe in detail an implementation such as you describe, I'll stick with dumb pointers and possibly smart arrays.

Comment: The whole standard is an as-if requirement :) I agree, that a bounds-checking implementation would break a lot of existing code. But that's not really a problem: I don't think a kernel shouldn't make use of constructs undefined by the C standard, but defined by a certain compiler (the Linux kernel, for example, isn't supposed to be compilable with any compiler but Gcc, and I don't think, anyone wants a run-time bounds-checking kernel). C is a language for low-level, machine-dependent stuff _and_ high-level end user applications, and one reason to have undefined aspects in the language [...]

Comment: [...] specification is to allow implementations to address only one of them (or something in between).

Comment: Probably best to leave it there, but most likely the only way to really get an answer is to ask a question and get an answer from someone privy to the thinking of the Committee. There is much hidden away in their minutes too.