# Portable C Implementation of Relative Pointers

Tags: c

I define relative pointer to mean what [Ginger Bill describes as Self-Relative Pointers](https://www.gingerbill.org/article/2020/05/17/relative-pointers/):

> ... define the base [to which an offset will be applied] to be the memory address of the offset itself

For example, consider this struct:

```
struct house {
  int32_t weight;
}
struct person {
  int32_t age;
  struct house* residence;
}
int32_t getPersonsHousesWeight(struct person* p) {
  return p->residence->weight;
}
```

The relative-pointer implementation of the same thing in C that I think might work is:

```
struct house { ... } // same as before
struct person {
  int32_t age;
  int64_t residence; // an offset from the person's address in memory
}
int32_t getPersonsHousesWeight(struct person* p) {
  return ((struct residence*)((char*)p + (p->residence)))->weight;
}
```

Assuming that alignment of everything is good (all 8 bytes), is this free of undefined behavior?

EDIT

@tstanisl has provided an excellent answer (which I've accepted) that thoroughly explains UB in the context of stack allocations. I am curious how allocation into a large slab of contiguous heap would impact this analysis. For example:

```
int foo(void) {
  char* base = mmap(NULL,4096,PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ,-1,MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS);
  // Omitting mmap error checking
  struct person* myPerson = (struct person*)(base + 128);
  struct house* myHouse = (struct house*)(base + 256);
  int32_t delta = (char*)myHouse - (char*)myPerson;
  // Does the computation of delta invoke UB?
}
```

Comment: For me, it depends on how you define the offset, if you set it at runtime like `p->residence = (intptr_t)p - (intptr_t)h` (assuming `person* p`, `house* h`) then it would work well.

Comment: it depends if the `p` and `struct house` object belong the same large object like `struct person_in_da_house { struct person p; struct house h; }`. Moreover, there are some technical condition on how the pointer `p` is constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is going to be UB.
The first case is when `person` and `house` belong to separate object.
In such a case it will be *UB* because the pointer arithmetics is performed outside of the object.

```
int foo(void) {
  struct person p;
  struct house h;
  p.residence = (char*)&h - (char*)&p; // already UB
  getPersonsHousesWeight(&p); // UB again
}
```

In practice it means that the compiler is not obligated to notice that objects accessed from a pointers constructed from `&p` can alias with object `h` because `p` and `h` are separete memory regions (aka objects).

When both objects are placed inside a larger object then the situation is a bit better. Though it still would be technical UB.

```
int foo(void) {
  struct ph {
    struct person p;
    struct house h;
  } ph;
  ph.p.residence = (char*)&ph.h - (char*)&ph.p; // still UB
  getPersonsHousesWeight(&ph.p); // UB again
}
```

It UB because pointer arithmetic is done outside the member object.
`(char*)&ph.h - 1` is a pointer outside of `ph.h`.

Note, that this code will likely work pretty much everywhere.
Otherwise, heavily used `container_of`-like macros would not work breaking a lot of existing code including the Linux kernel.

To avoid UB the pointer must be constructed in a special way to avoid moving outside of the originating object.
Rather using `&ph.h` one should use `(char*)&ph + offsetof(struct ph, h)`.
Similarly `&ph.p` should be replaced with `(char*)&ph + offsetof(struct ph, p)`.

Now this code should be portable:

```
int foo(void) {
  struct ph {
    struct person p;
    struct house h;
  } ph;
  struct person *p_ptr = (struct person*)((char*)&ph + offsetof(struct ph, p));
  struct house  *h_ptr = (struct house*) ((char*)&ph + offsetof(struct ph, h));
  ph.p.residence = (char*)h_ptr - (char*)p_ptr;
  getPersonsHousesWeight(p_ptr);
}
```

Though it is very obscure.
The interesting discussion on this topic can be found at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296019/can-a-container-of-macro-ever-be-strictly-conforming)

Comment: Thanks! This is very thorough. I've added an edit at the end of the original question to ask more specifically about the case of heap allocation. In the context of heap allocation, it is less clear to me what an "originating object" is. Is it the entire block of memory that the OS hands the user? Or does slicing into a block somehow change the originating pointer?

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin the C standard is agnostic about OS, heaps and stack. To be fully portable you should treat each pointer returned from malloc as being placed in a unique address space fully separated from everything else. I guess the relative pointers can  only be used for object created within a region returned from the same call to malloc().